# Unhandled IO exception ? Playing mp3 file with a media player - Android

Tags: android, audio, mp3

Here's my code:
(As an example, say I put this in the OnCreate to play sound when the activity starts up.)

```
AssetFileDescriptor afda = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
MediaPlayer player;
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Among other things, here's a solution I found on SO:

```
try {// above erroneous code here
     }
  mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried putting every statement that gave the Unhandled IO exception error in a try catch statement. But upon doing that the app goes ANR, doesn't start up and the logcat gives something like "Could not initialize MainActivity" ....

Upon further research I found that this code worked for everyone else, maybe I'm not adding something..

What's wrong with this code ? How to correct it ?

(OR, is there a better more efficient or easier way to play a file ? I only need Play/Pause functionality.)
(I have a [scrollable tab + swipe] navigation app, I want to play a different mp3 file on every tab's screen... just putting it in the oncreate for testing..)

Here's the modified code and the logcat for the runtime error it produces. Basically, all the statements that I've put in the the try catch box gives the "Unhandled exception type IO" compile time error.

Putting these 3 erroneous statements in the try catch results in no problem when compiling, but results in the activity not being able to start(see logcat output below the code)

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afda = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
MediaPlayer player;
player = new MediaPlayer();


try {
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
    player.prepare();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

player.start();

08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wn.w/wn.w.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at wn.w.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
08-13 16:00:41.869: E/AndroidRuntime(16412):    ... 11 more
```

At line 71 I have :
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
(this is within the try catch(see above code))

Comment: Post full Logcat... plz..

Comment: Done :) (see edit above)

Comment: MainActivity.java: Line 71   What is here??

Comment: player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());

Comment: Plz Check below code and replay..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
AssetFileDescriptor afda = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

with

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afda;
    try {
        afda = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (afd != null) {
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } else {
        Log.i("Check This", "AudioFile.mp3 really exist?  afd is null ");
    }
```

Comment: Unhandled exception type IOException, I reckon the problem is with the "afd" and "player" both

Comment: Can you put the audio into RAW file  and                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: Wait, lemme try.. btw that create() one gave the same error (null pointer)

Comment: Nope, :/ Same compiletime error in the if block (same as my first comment to this answer) ... I don't know why the player is causing this :/ Can I somehow make this easier with XML or any other solution?

Comment: BTW, in the player.create(..,..) you suggested above I initialized the Context variable to null...

Comment: Please try downloading source code from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: Oh my god, ... I basically copy pasted half my app from that exact source. That's where I started from ! :/